# Why does Code Analysis recommend that the first event parameter is "object sender" and not a more specific type?

Tags: c#, events, types, code-analysis, eventhandler

What is the reasoning behind CA1009's (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182133.aspx) that 'sender' should always be 'object'?

For example, I have an class like Car that emits Moved events.  I don't want Moved events being generated from any other classes.  I imagine most events are specific to a particular class hierarchy so why doesn't the rule allow any exceptions?

Comment: How do you know it was a Car that moved?  Could have been a Pedestrian.  Could be an Airplane.  You are not supposed to care, all that matters is that *something* moved.  If you want to know what *specific* object moved then all you need is reference identity.  Object is good enough for that.

Comment: I suppose it's for historical reasons. Events date back to .NET 1.0, which didn't have generics yet.

Comment: Note this is a "recommendation", not a "requirement" - excepting as such recommendations are treated as requirements.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm writing the API and I only want this event sent by Cars.  If I wanted the event to be sent by anything, i'd use object as the sender.

Comment: How could you possibly get that wrong?  It is up to the Car object to fire the event.  If it is a Pedestrian then just don't fire it.  Next year, you don't know that it might be something else.  Decoupling the observer from the object is a Really Big Deal.